# Home Page OwlCarousel How To Control What Products To Display

Tags: cms, home, blocks

I have two OwlCarousel on the Home Page, but don't see any thing on the backend that allow me to control what products I would like to display on these two.

The way this OwlCarousel is setup to display is CMS -> Page -> Home -> Content

```
{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml" category_id="101" product_count="12" hide_button="1" block_name="Featured Products"}}
{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml" category_id="100" product_count="12" hide_button="1" block_name="New Products"}}
```

[image: Home Page OwlCaruousel - How Do I control what Product to show and not show]

Answer (score 2):

I actually figure it out a way of doing this.

1. Create a Category and add the product that you want to display
2. Save it Category and get the ID number for it
3. For the code I replace the new ID with the bold font below. 
   CMS- -> Pages -> Home -> Content

   ```
   {{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml" category_id=**"101"** product_count="12" hide_button="1" block_name="Featured Products"}} {{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml" category_id="100" product_count="12" hide_button="1" block_name="New Products"}}
   ```
4. Save it and it should display these products on the frontend.
5. ONLY PROBLEM is I can't arrange the product in order from 1-12. It display the order in random I believe.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding point 5. ONLY PROBLEM...

If you go

Catalog -> Manage Categories

Then find your featured Category

You should see tabs like this...
[image: Category Products]
Then you will see the featured products.

On the right there is a position column like this...
[image: Position column example]

Hopefully you can now rearrange the position of the products in your product Carousel.

Answer (score 2):

how can we show specific product in slider on home page by passing product is like product_id="10,15,80,98" in collection.

```
{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml" category_id="101" product_count="12" hide_button="1" block_name="Featured Products"}
```

to

```
{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml" category_id="101" **product_id="10,15,80,98"** product_count="12" hide_button="1" block_name="Featured Products"}
```